# Deleting object from array in vue props

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am getting a very strange behavior while splicing the object from the array.

I have a js array with objects. I am passing it via props and populating a navigation based on it. Now when I try to delete it inside `created hood` it deleted half and keep half. 
Here is the code. Very simple

```
props: {
 navItems: {
  type: Array,
 },
},
```

In created hook I have

```
let nav = this.navItems
for(let j in nav){
  nav.splice(j,1)
}
console.log(nav) // print half item from the array. Shouldn't remove all?
this.nav = nav
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Lets take this array:

```
  [1, 2, 3]
```

If you remove the first element you end up at:

```
 [2, 3]
```

Now you remove the second element:

```
[2]
```

And the third:

```
 [2]
```

As you can see, you actually want to splice out the first element until the array is empty:

```
 while(nav.length)
   nav.splice(0, 1);
```

or just:

```
  nav.splice(0, nav.length);
```

Comment: Yap you are right, but actually I need the position to delete from any position I want. So j is needed here